# What is the time complexity of lookups and inserts in a Delphi TList?

Tags: delphi, time-complexity, tlist

The "TList" object in Delphi confuses me a bit with its "items[i]" property. This property hints that the TList might internally index all its list items in some kind of array.

I am fully aware though that such indexed properties can be handled arbitrarily inside objects (in this case e.g. hypothetically by traversing the entire linked list linearly until hitting the item with the provided index), so my question is therefore: Which of the following alternatives is the true one:

1.
TList does indeed internally index its items in some kind of (dynamic) array, and list item lookups with arbitrary indexes will therefore have a O(1) time complexity (i.e. constant), whereas list item adds will have a O(n) complexity (i.e. linear), since the array will have to be reallocated when expanded in size.

2.
TList does NOT internally index its items in some kind of (dynamic) array, and list item lookups with arbitrary indexes will therefore have a O(n) time complexity (i.e. linear), whereas list item adds will have a O(1) complexity (i.e. constant).

3.
Another third alternative, which you in this case are very welcome to explain the time complexity of when it comes to lookup (by index) and insert operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source code to the RTL is available with a purchase of Delphi, so it's easy to tell what's actually going on.

Under the hood, items are managed inside a dynamic array that grows as you add items to it, but in a more intelligent fashion than simply growing by 1 with each new addition.  This means that the backing array will usually be larger than the `Count` of items in the `TList` object, and so indexing is a `O(1)` operation and additions are usually `O(1)` as well.  (Especially since the FastMM memory manager can often reallocate an array in-place when it grows, especially at smaller sizes, so there's no copying required.)  But when the backing array has to grow and be copied by the memory manager, it will be an `O(n)` operation.

An `Insert` operation, on the other hand (inserting into the middle of the list, rather than adding on to the end) is an `O(n)` operation because it has to move everything after the insertion point forward by one.

As @SirRufo pointed out, the `Capacity` property is relevant here: it's the size of the backing array.  If `Count = Capacity` and you try to `Add` a new value, that's when it will have to resize the array.

Comment: The fact that adding is usually O(1) isn't really that important. What matters is the average complexity of adding. Or if each addition had a time constraint then the worst case complexity would be what counted. It's rather hard to analyse either of these.

Comment: Yes, O() does indeed imply **worst case** complexity, so average complexity is not relevant, I agree (although it can indeed still be interesting to know about the average complexity outside of the scope of the O() definition).

Comment: The [`TList<T>.Capacity`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList.Capacity) property is also worth to mention here

Comment: @Question My main point is that I don't think it's easy to say much about the complexity of an operation when there are heap allocations involved. And although Mason has said something, I believe that it is much more complex. Furthermore big O notation may not be useful at this point. What if there is heap contention? Or what if the perf is dominated by the constant rather than asymptotic behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Delphi's `TList` is a class that wraps an array. So the complexity of its operations are the same as an array. Random access is O(1). Insertion is O(n) for the copying part of the operation. The memory allocation associated with insertion is much harder to analyse and depends on many factors. I'm not sure it's really tractable to analyse the time complexity of insertion because of thois.

As an aside, it has always frustrated me that, from a computer science perspective, Delphi's list classes are not lists. They are arrays.

Comment: Thanks! Two follow-up questions then: 1: Does the same apply to "generics" lists, i.e. TList<T>. 2: Is there any "true" linked list class in Delphi, or will I have to implement this myself?

Comment: Btw, what is the recommended routine for assigning answers at Stack Exchange, is it to assign the quickest reply that fully answers the question (yours) as the answer, or the most comprehensive one (Mason Wheeler's)?

Comment: Same with `TList<T>`. Think of it as an array. That's what it is in perf terms. In the RTL there are no linked list classes. I'm sure that 3rd party libs offer that. Perhaps Spring4D has a linked list class.

Comment: Pick the answer you prefer. Don't pick the fastest. Pick the best in your opinion. I'm not sure that Mason was that much more comprehensive, but then I would say that! ;-) I chose not to repeat in the answer what you already know and said in the question about perf characteristics of arrays. Anyway, Mason's answer is good. Do feel free to accept it if you wish. I would be happy with that. Do feel free to vote for it too!

Comment: Thanks again, I'll assign Mason's reply as answer then, but upvote both!